# how i can connect frontend to backend in react native project to node js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

now i connect frontend to backend with ip address but i think when i will live project then how automatic server is start and how to automatic connect front end to backend

any body know about how my backend node server automatically run when user open the app in his/her mobile. where am i write code for automatic start backend node server in react native

package.json file in react native

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "web": "expo start --web",
  "eject": "expo eject"
},
```

Comment: in "production" (or as you call it "live"), the "backend server" code should always be running

Comment: Once you host the backend server, it should be live and running. So you don't need any special script to start the server from React Native side.

You can get the URL of the live server and just use it in your React Native app.